# How to make calculations after requesting with M2M fields (DRF)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ht = models.CharField(default=0)
    wd = models.CharField(default=0)
    len = models.CharField(default=0)

class Parcel(models.Model):
    product_list = models.ManyToManyField(Product)

class ParcelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Parcel
        fields = '__all__'

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_volume = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class ParcelCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Package.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PackageSerializer

class ParcelListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ParcelSerializer

class ProductCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    
class ProductListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

My output is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "products": [
            1
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "products": [
            1,
            2
        ]
    }
]
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/parcel/create

How can I get product id and product volume as below when I post parcel create? I didn't understand what to do because it's ManyToManyField. After the request comes, how can I get product ids from the body and calculate their volume

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "products": [
            1 : Result #Volume of ID : 1 Product (wd*ht*len)
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "products": [
            1 : Result #Volume of ID : 1 Product (wd*ht*len),
            2 : Result #Volume of ID : 1 Product (wd*ht*len)
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a serializer in your `ParcelSerializer`:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # …
    pass

class ParcelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ProductSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Parcel
        fields = '__all__'
```

You thus need to define the `ProductSerializer` first, and then use that in the `ParcelSerializer`.

If you want to return the outcome of `str(…)` on a `Product`, you can work with the [**`StringRelatedField`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield):

```
class ParcelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = StringRelatedField(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Parcel
        fields = '__all__'
```

then this will thus produce a list of strings.

Comment: After I tried your first method, I got an error to create parcel endpoint. `Products
Lists are not currently supported in HTML input.`

Comment: @turgovic: can you edit the question with the details of the request you made to the API?

Comment: @turgovic: but what request (GET/POST) and what data as "payload"?

Comment: POST request, json body, multiple product ID

Comment: @turgovic: but if you make a POST request with a nested serializer, you will need to post the details of these items as well (so a list of dictionaries). Otherwise you can work with another serializer (that works with primary keys) to handle the create/update logic, and work with the "new" serializer to retrieve data.